# Triple integral $\,\iiint_I (\frac{z}{1-|x|y})^2 dxdydz$

Tags: integration, solution-verification, volume

This is question 4 of Exercise 8(c) in *A Second Course in Mathematical Analysis (J. C. Burkill, H. Burkill)*.

> Let $I$ be the interval $[-1,2] \times [-1,0] \times [0,2]$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Show that $\displaystyle\iiint_I \left(\dfrac{z}{1-|x|y}\right)^2 dzdydx = 9 \log 6.$

I have attempted the question but not obtained the given answer. I can write the integral as iterated integrals
$$
I = \int_{-1}^2 \int_{-1}^0 \int_{0}^2 \dfrac{z^2}{(1-|x|y)^2} dz dy dx $$

I can [evaluate](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate%20z%5E2%20dz%20from%200%20to%202) $\int_0^2 z^2 dz = 8/3$. I include a WolframAlpha link for verification.

This means that I can proceed by writing $$ I = \int_{-1}^2 \int_{-1}^0 \dfrac{8}{3} (1-|x|y)^{-2} dy dx.$$

Now, I can [evaluate](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate%20%281-%7Cx%7Cy%29%5E%28-2%29%20dy%20from%20-1%20to%200) $\int_{-1}^0 (1-|x|y)^{-2} dy = (1 + |x|)^{-1}.$

Finally, the last integral is $\displaystyle\int_{-1}^2 \dfrac{8}{3}\big(1+|x|\big)^{-1} dx$ which I do by splitting it into two integrals, one from $-1$ to $0$ and the other from $0$ to $2$. [This gives me](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate%208%2F%5B3%281%20%2B%20abs%28x%29%29%5D%20from%20-1%20to%202) $\dfrac{8}{3} \log 6$.

I could check my final result using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=triple%20integral%20calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22TripleIntegral%22%2C%20%22rangeend2m%22%7D%20-%3E%220%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22TripleIntegral%22%2C%20%22rangeend1i%22%7D%20-%3E%222%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22TripleIntegral%22%2C%20%22intvariable1i%22%7D%20-%3E%22z%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22TripleIntegral%22%2C%20%22rangestart3%22%7D%20-%3E%22-1%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22TripleIntegral%22%2C%20%22rangestart2m%22%7D%20-%3E%22-1%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22TripleIntegral%22%2C%20%22integrand%22%7D%20-%3E%22z%5E2%2F%281-%7Cx%7Cy%29%5E2%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22TripleIntegral%22%2C%20%22rangestart1i%22%7D%20-%3E%220%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22TripleIntegral%22%2C%20%22intvariable2m%22%7D%20-%3E%22y%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22TripleIntegral%22%2C%20%22intvariable3%22%7D%20-%3E%22x%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22TripleIntegral%22%2C%20%22rangeend3%22%7D%20-%3E%222%22), which seems to agree.

Could someone please let me know if this is a misprint in the book or if there is a flaw in my working? Thank you!